# How to set header and footer text alongside page number in a C# VSTO Word Add-in?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, footer, add-in

I need to set the header/footer text alongside the page number in a C# VSTO Word add-in.  I can insert the text OR I can insert the page number, but when I do both, I can't get one or the other to stay on specific sides of the page.

For example, on odd pages, I need the header to be:  TITLE  PageNumber.  On even pages, I need the header to be:  PageNumber  AUTHOR.  The footer needs to be the same.  Odd page header is text aligned to the left, page number aligned to the right.  Even page header is page number aligned to the left, author aligned to the right.  Footer is always centered.

How can I get this arrangement of text and page number in a C# VSTO Word Add-in (MSVS 2015)?  (I can't find this detailed assistance anywhere on SO or the net.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is a delicate dance of alignment, application-level selection, range manipulation and use of Tab-Alignments.  This is the function I developed.  It creates three sections in a document (title page, body and end pages), and then it formats the header/footer for each, removing these features from the first and third section, while setting them as per the question within the middle, or body, section.  Code is commented to explain:  (NOTE:  Page number MUST insert first, then the alignment-tab, and then the text BUT the text is added at the application-selection level and NOT directly to the header/footer range.)

```
    private void DoFormatSections(Document docFormat, string strAuthor, string strTitle, string strCollectionTitle)
    {
        try
        {
            //  Three ranges to establish three sections, title, body and end statement
            Range rngTitlePage = null;
            Range rngBody = null;
            Range rngEndPage = null;
            //  Odd pages header
            HeaderFooter hPrimary = null;
            //  Even pages header
            HeaderFooter hEven = null;
            //  Odd pages footer
            HeaderFooter fPrimary = null;
            //  Even pages footer
            HeaderFooter fEven = null;

            //  Body begins at page three; (1 and 2 are title page)
            int nBodyBegin = 3;
            //  Body ends at third page from end (next to last is end remark and last is author about)
            int nBodyEnd = (int)docFormat.Paragraphs[docFormat.Paragraphs.Count].Range.get_Information(WdInformation.wdNumberOfPagesInDocument) - 1;

            // -1 = true; odd and even pages have separate header and footer; so, setup both
            docFormat.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = -1;

            //  Set start of begin and end of end from total document range (document will have one section containing everything by default)
            rngTitlePage = docFormat.Sections[1].Range;
            rngEndPage = docFormat.Sections[1].Range;

            //  Set the ranges of the three sections, range is by character index within the document
            //  Move to first character of body section
            wordApp.Selection.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute, nBodyBegin, null);
            rngTitlePage.End = wordApp.Selection.Range.Start - 1;
            rngBody = wordApp.Selection.Range;
            //  Move to last character of body section
            wordApp.Selection.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute, nBodyEnd, null);
            rngBody.End = wordApp.Selection.Range.Start - 1;
            rngEndPage.Start = wordApp.Selection.Range.Start;                

            //  Add two sections to document (order is unimportant for now, each section below sets the range appropriately for each section
            docFormat.Sections.Add(rngEndPage, WdSectionStart.wdSectionContinuous);
            docFormat.Sections.Add(rngBody, WdSectionStart.wdSectionContinuous);

            //  Disconnect second section (body) from first and third sections;  set section section (body) header and footer
            if (docFormat.Sections.Count >= 2)
            {
                //  Ensure odd/even header/footer is separated for this section
                docFormat.Sections[2].PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = -1;

                //  Set section range, body
                docFormat.Sections[2].Range.Start = rngBody.Start;
                docFormat.Sections[2].Range.End = rngBody.End;

                //  Odd page footer:  collection title
                fPrimary = docFormat.Sections[2].Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
                if (fPrimary != null)
                {
                    //  Disconnect this footer from previous section
                    fPrimary.LinkToPrevious = false;

                    //  Set and format footer text
                    fPrimary.Range.Text = strCollectionTitle;
                    fPrimary.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
                    fPrimary.Range.Font.Size = 10;
                    fPrimary.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
                }

                //  Even page footer:  collection title
                fEven = docFormat.Sections[2].Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages];
                if (fEven != null)
                {
                    //  Disconnect this footer from previous section
                    fEven.LinkToPrevious = false;

                    //  Set and format footer text
                    fEven.Range.Text = strCollectionTitle;
                    fEven.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
                    fEven.Range.Font.Size = 10;
                    fEven.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
                }

                //  Odd page header
                hPrimary = docFormat.Sections[2].Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
                if(hPrimary != null)
                {
                    //  Disconnect this header from previous section
                    hPrimary.LinkToPrevious = false;

                    //  Odd page number header:  Title -> PageNumber

                    //  Page number MUST come first (it deletes all existing header text, if later)
                    PageNumber pnPrimary = null;
                    hPrimary.PageNumbers.RestartNumberingAtSection = true;
                    hPrimary.PageNumbers.StartingNumber = 1;
                    //hPrimary.PageNumbers.ShowFirstPageNumber = true;
                    pnPrimary = hPrimary.PageNumbers.Add(WdPageNumberAlignment.wdAlignPageNumberRight, true);
                    if (pnPrimary != null)
                        pnPrimary.Alignment = WdPageNumberAlignment.wdAlignPageNumberRight;
                    hPrimary.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;

                    //  Move to start of header
                    hPrimary.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart);

                    //  Insert alignment tab
                    wordApp.Selection.Range.InsertAlignmentTab((int)WdAlignmentTabAlignment.wdRight, (int)WdAlignmentTabRelative.wdMargin);

                    //  Move again to start of header
                    hPrimary.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart);

                    //  Set selection range text (NOT the range text on the hPrimary object)
                    wordApp.Selection.Range.InsertBefore(strTitle);
                    wordApp.Selection.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
                    wordApp.Selection.Range.Font.Size = 10;
                    //wordApp.Selection.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;
                }

                //  Even page header
                hEven = docFormat.Sections[2].Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages];
                if(hEven != null)
                {
                    //  Disconnect this header from previous section
                    hEven.LinkToPrevious = false;

                    //  Even page number header:  PageNumber -> Author

                    //  Page number MUST come first (it deletes all existing header text, if later)
                    PageNumber pnEven = null;
                    pnEven = hEven.PageNumbers.Add(WdPageNumberAlignment.wdAlignPageNumberLeft, true);
                    if (pnEven != null)
                        pnEven.Alignment = WdPageNumberAlignment.wdAlignPageNumberLeft;

                    //  Move to end of header
                    hEven.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);

                    //  Insert alignment tab
                    wordApp.Selection.Range.InsertAlignmentTab((int)WdAlignmentTabAlignment.wdRight, (int)WdAlignmentTabRelative.wdMargin);

                    //  Move again to end of header
                    hEven.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);

                    //  Set selection range text (NOT the range text on the hEven object)
                    wordApp.Selection.Range.InsertAfter(strAuthor);
                    wordApp.Selection.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
                    wordApp.Selection.Range.Font.Size = 10;
                    wordApp.Selection.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;
                }
            }

            //  Clear first section header and footer
            if (docFormat.Sections.Count >= 1)
            {
                //  Ensure odd/even header/footer is separated for this section
                docFormat.Sections[1].PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = -1;

                //  Set section range, body
                docFormat.Sections[1].Range.Start = rngTitlePage.Start;
                docFormat.Sections[1].Range.End = rngTitlePage.End;

                //  Odd page header, clear
                hPrimary = docFormat.Sections[1].Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
                if (hPrimary != null)
                {
                    //  Disconnect, select and clear
                    hPrimary.LinkToPrevious = false;
                    hPrimary.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.Delete();
                }

                //  Even page header, clear
                hEven = docFormat.Sections[1].Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages];
                if (hEven != null)
                {
                    //  Disconnect, select and clear
                    hEven.LinkToPrevious = false;
                    hEven.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.Delete();
                }

                //  Odd page footer, clear
                fPrimary = docFormat.Sections[1].Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
                if (fPrimary != null)
                {
                    //  Disconnect, select and clear
                    fPrimary.LinkToPrevious = false;
                    fPrimary.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.Delete();
                }

                //  Even page footer, clear
                fEven = docFormat.Sections[1].Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages];
                if (fEven != null)
                {
                    //  Disconnect, select and clear
                    fEven.LinkToPrevious = false;
                    fEven.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.Delete();
                }
            }

            //  Clear third section header and footer
            if (docFormat.Sections.Count >= 3)
            {
                //  Ensure odd/even header/footer is separated for this section
                docFormat.Sections[3].PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = -1;

                //  Set section range, body
                docFormat.Sections[3].Range.Start = rngTitlePage.Start;
                docFormat.Sections[3].Range.End = rngTitlePage.End;

                //  Odd page header, clear
                hPrimary = docFormat.Sections[3].Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
                if (hPrimary != null)
                {
                    //  Disconnect, select and clear
                    hPrimary.LinkToPrevious = false;
                    hPrimary.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.Delete();
                }

                //  Even page header, clear
                hEven = docFormat.Sections[3].Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages];
                if (hEven != null)
                {
                    //  Disconnect, select and clear
                    hEven.LinkToPrevious = false;
                    hEven.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.Delete();
                }

                //  Odd page footer, clear
                fPrimary = docFormat.Sections[3].Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
                if (fPrimary != null)
                {
                    //  Disconnect, select and clear
                    fPrimary.LinkToPrevious = false;
                    fPrimary.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.Delete();
                }

                //  Even page footer, clear
                fEven = docFormat.Sections[3].Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages];
                if (fEven != null)
                {
                    //  Disconnect, select and clear
                    fEven.LinkToPrevious = false;
                    fEven.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.Delete();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error [DoFormatSections]: " + ex);
        }

        return;
    }
```